# Jekyll Static Site not generating html for internal links

Tags: jekyll

Attempting to covert our site documentation to a Jekyll Static Site. Everything "runs" fine _site filled with all index.html at each of the sub level directories, BUT none of the

example

```
    ---
    title: ___1_0_background_index_md
    ---

    1. ([Introduction](./1.1_intro.md))  
    2. ([Terminology](./1.2_terminology.md)

    -----
```

comes out as

```
    <li>(<a href="./1.1_intro.md">Introduction</a>)</li>
    <li>(<a href="./1.2_terminology.md">Terminology</a></li>
```

e.g. the links are still to the .md files not the generated html files. the html files are generated.

really unsure what i'm doing wrong? I've checked

- all files have front matter
- there is an index.md in each sub folder
- tried to remove additional brackets around the links e.g. name versus (name

note: I auto generated the title front matter across all our files, hence the title is simplified original filenames.

any guidance much appreciated?

thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace the .md extension to .html using any text editor. I would recommend [Grepwin](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html) for Mass search and replacement.

So this will work as you've intended:

```
---
title: ___1_0_background_index_md
---

1. ([Introduction](./1.1_intro.html)  
2. ([Terminology](./1.2_terminology.html)

-----
```

Comment: Thanks This did work I guess I was under the impression that having .md during creation allows me to edit the files using mou (or other md editor) and that these would automatically be turned into html for final content. Seems I have to use a script before html generation ...